# What is the meaning behind the ant logo of "The Prodigy"?

Tags: meaning, artwork

[*The Prodigy*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Prodigy) are an English electronic music band formed in the 1990's. The band has used [several logos](https://logos.fandom.com/wiki/The_Prodigy) through the decades. In particular, from the [mid-1990s to 2000](https://logos.fandom.com/wiki/The_Prodigy#1995-1996) their logo featured an image of an ant. Does anyone know about the real meaning behind their ant logo?

Comment: The name of the group comes from the keyboard Liam Howlett used to create many of the early releases.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I asked my friend Paul, currently sunning himself in Spain, and listening to the Prodigy back catalogue, and he found [this Instagram post](https://www.instagram.com/p/BqkdtrglbKQ/)  from which this quote :

> Last wednesday, November 21, Liam Howlett gave the special interview
>   for theprodigy.ru, where he noticed: «The ant is used because they are
>   small and powerfull, that's how we think of ourselves — you might not
>   hear from us for a bit and then BLAMMM! But if you look closely, we
>   are always there».

I can't locate the Nov 21 2018 interview, but sounds like this is it.